# Kohana 3.1 Pagination Links Issue

Tags: php, pagination, kohana

I have done the pagination in Kohana 3.1 using the following code in my controller page .How can I display the Pagination links in my view page ? Is this the correct way ??? or any issue with my code ?

```
public function action_imagelist()
       {  
         $per_page =2;
         $page_num = $this->request->param('page', 1);
         $offset   = ($page_num - 1) * $per_page;
         $view =View::factory('image/imagelist')->bind('page_links',$page_links)->bind('results', $results)->bind('pagination', $pagination);

    // Get the total count of records in the database
     $userid = Auth::instance()->get_user()->pk();  
     $count=ORM::factory('user_image')->where('app_userid','=',$userid)->count_all(); 


     // Create an instance of Pagination class and set values
     $pagination = Pagination::factory(array( 

      'total_items'    => $count,
      'current_page'   => array('source' => 'image/imagelist', 'key' => 'page'), 
      'items_per_page' => $per_page,
      'offset'  =>  $offset,
      'view'    =>  'pagination/basic'
  ));


      // Load specific results for current page
  $results = DB::select()->from('user_images')
            ->where('app_userid','=',$userid)
            ->order_by('image_id','ASC')
            ->limit($pagination->items_per_page)
            ->offset($pagination->offset)->execute();

// print_r($results);
 $page_links = $pagination;
 $this->template->content=$view->render();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display pagination, in your view print out `$page_links`.

You should read how stuff is divided in [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)!

Comment: ,I know that the print out will give the pagination result.I have worked with Kohana 2.X for more than 1 year .Just started using K3.1Here the problem is that the printout is giving the page links as
 `<p class="pagination">
First
 
Previous
 
<strong>1</strong>
 
  
 
     <a href="#">2</a> 
  
 
     <a href="#">3</a> 
  
 
     <a href="#">4</a> 
  
 
   <a href="#" rel="next">Next</a> 
 
   <a href="#" rel="last">Last</a> 
 
</p>`   Without the page redirection .Is there any  configuration I'm missing in the  the **pagination** module ??.

Comment: You can edit the view for pagination. Just pass `'template' => 'over/the/rainbow'` to `Pagination::factory()`.

Comment: What is the use of adding the template to the pagination ?
I am having the problem that the  when i render the pagination object I am getting  it as this 
`
<p class="pagination">

   First 
   Previous 
 
     <strong>1</strong>
  
 
     <a href="#">2</a>
  
 
     <a href="#">3</a>
  
 
   <a href="#" rel="next">Next</a>
 
   <a href="#" rel="last">Last</a>
 
</p>`